# How to manage a standalone media folder?

Tags: uploads, media

Managing my Wordpress installation with Git is great. I get to deploy fixes via command line (with Capistrano), easy rollback plan, the Theme folder is a standalone project added as a submodule -- This seems like a good way to handle Wordpress' and its plugins rapid updates.

However, Source Control is not right for handling the on-growing Uploads folder under `wp-content` folder.

The solution, IMHO, was to create a dedicated part on my server for media, and exclude it from the project itself. This way, I can backup media in a standalone process, deploy new version without having to clone the entire 300MB folder again and again -- in short, this seems like a good solution.

Wordpress doesn't do that, though. Not out of the box.

Possible solutions:

- Uploads files via FTP and use the image URL in posts (doubles the posting process time)
- Use a 3rd party image hosting (Flickr, Tumblr) -- This creates a dependency I wish to avoid. I want the media on my server, under my control.

Any other ideas? How can I achieve a standalone media folder to which I can upload files from WP dashboard?

Comment: While this is an incredibly interesting question, I'm really not so sure that it is *in scope*, since, while in the *context* of WordPress, neither the question itself nor the answer is in any way *specific* to WordPress.

Comment: I think you should re-consider a 3rd party host like rackspace or amazon for images (not an image host), extremely easy to manage when set up and it solves many problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would some form of this solution work? [Capistrano: Managing an uploads folder](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/02/capistrano-uploads-folder/) describes a way to update the symlink when deploying so you don't lose the uploads folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just come up with this interesting question today. This is what I have tried:

**1. Setup a TLD `example.com` and a sub domain `media.example.com`**:

Example with Nginx:

```
server_name example.com;
root /var/www/example.com;

server_name media.example.com;
root /var/www/media.example.com;
```

Make sure both sites is available and Nginx can write to the `/var/www/media.example.com` directory.

**2. Filter `upload_dir` in the `example.com` site**:

You can use these lines of code as a plugin or put directly into themes:

```
add_filter('upload_dir', function($uploads)
{
  $uploads = array_merge($uploads, [
    'url'     => 'http://media.example.com',
    'path'    => '/var/www/media.example.com',
    'baseurl' => 'http://media.example.com',
    'basedir' => '/var/www/media.example.com',
  ]);

  return $uploads;
}, PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Now, upload a new media file to `example.com` site. It should work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think .gitignore will help you:

http://help.github.com/ignore-files/

Comment: No good. Since I deploy with Capistrano, each deploy process clones the project and switches CURRENT symlink to new release folder. If I ignore uploads, I actually lose the uploads directory. The fail here is within the basic idea of including the media inside the project, and not in a seperate media server.